# CALL "C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node.exe" Errors

Tags: node.js, windows, npm, cmd

[image]

Installing node.js and npm showing this error together with

> "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" prefix -g' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>       operable program or batch file.
>       6.4.1

Changing path, environment variables and comspec didn't help.

Comment: You have double backslashes.

Comment: When i install it, it automatically adds double slashes i dont know why but in my environment variable  it dont have backslashes

Comment: you got solution? @Jan Andrei Cruz

Answer (score 0):

go to Environment variables>Sytem variables and then click on CompSpec 
and remove any path after 
"%SystemRoot%\system32\cmd.exe"
There should be only one path and it should be 
"%SystemRoot%\system32\cmd.exe"

Sometimes Git path will be there 
[image: Screen Shot]